# Import of file from Excel to R without referring to column i.e. A:H and calling specific Columns by their names without the entire dataset

Tags: r, excel, import, readxl

Is there away to import specific columns from Excel into R such that R doesn't read the whole files but only the specific columns that I want it to read? This should not be using any Excel column Reference directly i.e. columns A:H as there is a possibility of column order changing.

I created a column list and tried to import it using read_excel function and used the column list to import only those columns. However, when there are additional columns in the excel file R tried to read those columns as well. Is there any function that only reads the columns that I need without reading the whole file and then creating a data frame in R.

Out of Name,Alpha,Beta,Gamma columns I only need values in "Name","Alpha","Beta" and don't want R to even read "Gamma" column values.

```
col_list=c("Name","Alpha","Beta")

Month1_2020 <- read_excel("Complete Data.xlsx", sheet = "Month1_2020")[c(col_list)]
```

Comment: I don't see anything inside the [read_excel](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readxl/versions/0.1.1/topics/read_excel) documentation which lets you read some of the columns but not others. Seems like you have to read everything and filter it afterward.

Comment: @NickODell is there any other function apart from read_excel that can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach which works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_xlsx_File <- "D:/Excel_File.xlsx"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_xlsx_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets()

rng <- Sheets[[1]]$Range("A:A")
vec_Val <- unlist(rng$Value()) # Get values of range A
```